# How do loose connections cause overheating, arcing and start a fires?

Tags: connector

I am confused as to how a conductor can became overheated when it's connection to the circuit is unintentionally loosened.

A loose connection will cause the resistance to increase and decrease the current. Why does the temperature increase if the current decreases? Is my understanding wrong?

I have a hypothesis that is it because of the reduction in the contacting surface area that causes a potential difference at the surface. Since there is a voltage drop across the contacting surface it will seem like a load to the power source and will consume power. Which means that it will transform electrical energy to heat energy. Am I right?

I understand why an arc is produced at the moment when a connection is opened. It is because of the ionization of air particle by the large electric-field when the resistance is not high enough to break the circuit. My question is whether this arc will produce heat or not? If yes, then why? Is it because of the ionization process itself? How does this process take place?

I am weak in atomic theory, can anyone explain to me the energy flow when ionization occurs?

Comment: Write yourself a schematic, representing the contact as a resistor. Then calculate the power loss over that resistor.

Comment: I think that I've maintained the intended meaning in those edits, if not then please clarify what you were asking.

Comment: You exactly answered my question. Previously I wondered to represent the contact as a resistor in series to the load, but I couldn't confirm where the heat came from. Now I understand already, thank you so much.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A loose connection causes a local increase in resistance.

While the current will decrease, don't assume it will decrease much. For instance if you have 240v driving 12A through a 20ohm kettle, then one extra ohm in series will result in a new current that is still more than 11 amps.

The local heating will be given by \$I^2R\$, or 11*11*1 = 121 watts. Where the previous 2880 watts was being dissipated in the nicely water-cooled bulk of the kettle element, this shift of 121 watts into the loose contact is being dissipated in the tiny 1mm3 region of the loose contact surfaces, and will cause rapid and catastrophic heating.

An arc is basically a resistor, as far as power dissipation is concerned. It's the collisions between ions and free electrons, and their impacts into the contacts, that lose energy.

Comment: Additionally, the resistance will increase further as the contact point deteriorates with soot and char or whatever else happens from the arcing. There isn't always a thermal event though. Sometimes the connection just fails.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the answer is quite simple. Your initial conclusions are correct, but not all of them.

In every connection that is not perfect (which in fact is quite impossible to obtain for it would have to be exactly like the conductors - transversal area, shape, material, crystalline structure and so on), the flow of electrons behave differently from the rest of the conductor. If the connection is "loose", in fact, it means that transversal area trough which electrons flow will have to go has been reduced (a bit or a lot).

Also, do not forget that in real applications, conductors have resistance. So a simple DC circuit which would be a battery dV, and a resistor R connected to the battery, indeed is a series of 3 resistors R1+R+R2, in which R1 and R2 represent the resistance of the conductors.

So, if connection is loose between R1 and R, you may think of this as an introduction of a new resistance, say R4, now having R1+R4+R+R2. Of course, total current in the circuit drops. At the limit resistance grows so high that it becomes an isolator and no current at all passes trough it, leading to no heat dissipation at all (P=V^2 / R; if R -->inf P-->0).

So, if the current drops, heat dissiapation naturally also drops in R1, R and R2. BUT R4 didn't exist and was introduced, so there is a new source of heat dissipation for the now smaller current, which is R4. But remember, R4 is a resistor that represents the loose connection.

Thus, in that position which has small transversal area (much smaller than the conductor) and quite small length happens to flow a current that, altough lower than the previous, is high for the small transversal area, making that part of the conductor and the conecting point of R heat. Too many electrons to flow through small area. And the heat increases even further the local resistance, as the electrons cloud in the cristallyne becomes "agitated" leading to difficulties in estabilishing a one way electron flow, leading to more eltronic shocks, and thus further heat.

Comment: I'd hate to read the books you read if they all look like this!

Comment: The answer may be quite simple, but your wall-of-text is too hard to read. Please split it into paragraphs.

Answer (score -1):

A simple way to think about the reason for heat buildup at a loose electrical connection is to consider the law of physics that states that energy is a conserved quantity; it can be neither created nor destroyed.  It can only be converted from one form to another; light energy, heat energy, potential energy, kinetic energy, etc.  So, in an electrical circuit, voltage (a form of potential energy) accelerates electrons through the circuit wiring. The potential energy of the voltage has now been converted to the kinetic energy of the moving electrons.  When those electrons reach a loose connections, their flow is impeded, meaning they must lose some of their kinetic energy.  But the law of energy conservation says the lost kinetic energy must go somewhere, and it does.  It is dissipated in the form of heat energy.